# WPF tree view visibility converters not updating when item is added to bound observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, treeviewitem

I have built out a tree view that is bound to an observable collection and have built it with connecting lines between each tree view item. The view model being used implements INotifyPropertyChanged and I'm using PropertyChanged.Fody for weaving. The tree view is bound to the collection and is updating great EXCEPT for one thing. When I add a new item to the list during runtime, the UI doesn't seem to update properly. I have tried everything under the sun that I could find searching the web on how to force an update to the UI without having to send a command to rebuild the entire tree when I add a root item, which does work, but there has to be another way I'm not finding.

I am using Ninject for dependency injection.

I'll place all of the code below my question, for reference. Again, all of this is working great, until an item is added to the collection at runtime. The item is added and visible in the tree view once added to the collection, but the last line converter doesn't update all the graphics properly.

Considering the following image:

[image: Tree view after a root level item is added]

Once an item is added, the node that now becomes second to last, his connecting lines visibility does not update and he still thinks he's the last on the branch. I've tried all types of UI refresh methods I could find, nothing worked. I'm missing something here, but am fairly new to WPF. Any advice anyone can provide would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

**Here's how I'm initially building the tree view, which works great:**

```
ProjectHelpers.JsonObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(ProjectPath.BaseDataFullPath));

//-- Get the channels, which are the top level tree elements
var children = ProjectHelpers.GetChannels();

//-- add the channels to the application channel collection
IoC.Application.Channels = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItemViewModel>();

foreach(var c in children)
    IoC.Application.Channels.Add(new ProjectTreeItemViewModel(c.Path, ProjectItemType.Channel));
```

**Which is contained within this class:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The view model for the main project tree view
    /// </summary>
    public class ProjectTreeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the image displayed above the tree view UI
        /// </summary>
        public string RootImageName => "blink";

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public ProjectTreeViewModel()
        {
            BuildProjectTree();
        }

        #region Handlers : Building project data tree

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds the entire project tree
        /// </summary>
        public void BuildProjectTree()
        {

            ProjectHelpers.JsonObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(ProjectPath.BaseDataFullPath));

            //-- Get the channels, which are the top level tree elements
            var children = ProjectHelpers.GetChannels();

            //-- add the channels to the application channel collection
            IoC.Application.Channels = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItemViewModel>();

            foreach(var c in children)
                IoC.Application.Channels.Add(new ProjectTreeItemViewModel(c.Path, ProjectItemType.Channel));               
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**The view model for the items that get added to the observable collection**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The view model that represents an item within the tree view
    /// </summary>
    public class ProjectTreeItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The JSONPath for the item</param>
        /// <param name="type">The type of project item type</param>
        public ProjectTreeItemViewModel(string path = "", ProjectItemType type = ProjectItemType.Channel)
        {
            //-- Create commands
            ExpandCommand = new RelayCommand(Expand);
            GetNodeDataCommand = new RelayCommand(GetNodeData);

            FullPath = path;
            Type = type;

            //-- Setup the children as needed
            ClearChildren();
        }

        #region Public Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// The JSONPath for this item
        /// </summary>
        public string FullPath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The type of project item
        /// </summary>
        public ProjectItemType Type { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets and sets the image name associated with project tree view headers.
        /// </summary>
        public string ImageName
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Type)
                {
                    case ProjectItemType.Channel:
                        return "channel";

                    case ProjectItemType.Device:
                        return "device";

                    default:
                        return "blink";

                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the item as a string
        /// </summary>
        public string Name => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "Name");

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the associated driver as a string
        /// </summary>
        public string Driver => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "Driver");

        /// <summary>
        /// A list of all children contained inside this item
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItemViewModel> Children { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if this item can be expanded
        /// </summary>
        public bool CanExpand => (Type != ProjectItemType.Device);

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the tree view item is selected, bound to the UI
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if the current item is expanded or not
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get {
                return (Children?.Count(f => f != null) >= 1);
            }
            set {
                //-- If the UI tells us to expand...
                if (value == true)
                    //-- Find all children
                    Expand();
                //-- If the UI tells us to close
                else
                    this.ClearChildren();
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region Commands

        /// <summary>
        /// The command to expand this item
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ExpandCommand { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Command bound by left mouse click on tree view item
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand GetNodeDataCommand { get; set; }

        #endregion


        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Expands a tree view item
        /// </summary>
        public void Expand()
        {
            //-- return if we are either a device or already expanded
            if (this.Type == ProjectItemType.Device || this.IsExpanded == true)
                return;

            //-- find all children
            var children = ProjectHelpers.GetChildrenByName(FullPath, "Devices");
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItemViewModel>(
                            children.Select(c => new ProjectTreeItemViewModel(c.Path, ProjectHelpers.GetItemType(FullPath))));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears all children of this node
        /// </summary>
        public void ClearChildren()
        {
            //-- Clear items
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItemViewModel>();

            //-- Show the expand arrow if we are not a device
            if (this.Type != ProjectItemType.Device)
                this.Children.Add(null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears the children and expands it if it has children
        /// </summary>
        public void Reset()
        {
            this.ClearChildren();

            if (this.Children?.Count > 0)
                this.Expand();
        }

        #endregion


        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the view model data in the node context data grid
        /// </summary>
        public void GetNodeData()
        {
            switch (Type)
            {
                //-- get the devices associated with that channel
                case ProjectItemType.Channel:
                    IoC.Application.UpdateDeviceDataContext(FullPath);
                    break;

                //-- get the tags associated with that device
                case ProjectItemType.Device:
                    IoC.Application.UpdateTagDataContext(FullPath);
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Here's my template for the tree view item:**

```
<Style x:Key="BaseTreeViewItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TreeViewItemZIndexConverter}}" />
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,2,2,2"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid Name="ItemRoot">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Name="Lines" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- L shape -->
                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="TargetLine" BorderThickness="1 0 0 1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderBrush="Red"/>

                        <!-- line that follows a tree view item -->
                        <Border Name="LineToNextItem"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource TreeLineVisibilityConverter}}"
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderBrush="Blue"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                              Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                              ClickMode="Press"/>

                    <!-- selected border background -->
                    <Border Name="ContentBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentHeader" ContentSource="Header" MinWidth="20"/>
                    </Border>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1 0 0 0"
                                Name="TargetBorder"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                BorderBrush="Olive"
                                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=LineToNextItem, Path=Visibility}"
                                />
                    </Grid>

                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentHeader" Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentHeader" Property="MinHeight" Value="19"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OffWhiteBaseBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTreeViewItemColor}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </MultiTrigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**My custom tree view control**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">

            <StackPanel Background="Transparent"
                        Margin="8"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left">

                <Image x:Name="Root"
                       ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpened"
                       Width="18" Height="18"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       Margin="2.7 0 0 3"
                       Source="{Binding RootImageName, Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}" />

                <TreeView Name="ProjectTreeView"
                          Loaded="OnTreeViewLoaded"
                          SelectedItemChanged="OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged"
                          ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpened"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                          Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BaseTreeViewTemplate}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BaseTreeViewItemTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationViewModel.Channels, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.Instance}}">

                    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="New Item" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Cut" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Diagnostics" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Properties" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TreeView.ContextMenu>

                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                                <Image Width="15" Height="15" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                                        Margin="-1 0 0 0"
                                        Source="{Binding Path=ImageName, Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}" />

                                <TextBlock Margin="6,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>

                <ContentPresenter />

            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

**The visibility converter for the connection lines in the tree view template**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Visibility converter for a connecting line inside the tree view UI
    /// </summary>
    public class TreeLineVisibilityConverter : BaseValueConverter<TreeLineVisibilityConverter>
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType = null, object parameter = null, CultureInfo culture = null)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)value;
            ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

            bool isLastItem = (ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == ic.Items.Count - 1);
            return isLastItem ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your item model look like, does it have a reference to the parent?

Comment: Is your output window indicating any cast or converter failures when you update the collection?

Comment: @BionicCode I edited the post to include the full view model for the items that are added to the main observable collection and the class where the tree is initially created. Do I need another field in the **ProjectTreeItemViewModel** class to link it to the parent collection? As of now, I set the data context in the tree view control as a new instance of the **ProjectTreeViewModel** and bind the ItemSource to the Channels collection that is declared in the ApplicationViewModel, so that I can reference the collection anywhere through the IoC.

Comment: @Tronald No converter failures or errors occur at all, actually.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted an answer. For performance reasons you could consider to add a `Parent` property to your `ProjectTreeItemViewModel`. It's more efficient to traverse the model tree than traversing the visual tree. Then in your `ControlTemplate` you simply replace the binding to the `TemplatedParent` with a binding to the `DataContext`, which will return the current `ProjectTreeItemViewModel`. From here you can check if it's the last by accessing the `ProjectTreeItemViewModel.Children` property via the `Parent` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exists due to this binding:

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource TreeLineVisibilityConverter}}"
```

You are binding to the the item container itself. This value never changes, therefore the `Binding` is only triggered once when the template is being applied to the container.

You should bind to a property that changes too, whenever the `ItemsSource` changes. I think the best solution is one that moves this logic to the items and/or the converter.

For this purpose I've added an `IsLast` property to the data model `ProjectTreeItemViewModel` which must raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` on changes.
The initial default value of this property should be `false`.

The border visibility binds to this property using your existing, but modified `TreeLineVisibilityConverter`.

The converter has to be turned into a `IMultiValueConverter` as we need to bind to the new `ProjectTreeItemViewModel.IsLast` and to the item itself using a `MultiBinding`.

Whenever a new item is added to the `TreeView`, its template will be loaded. This will trigger the `MultiBinding` and therefore the `IMultiValueConverter`. The converter checks if the current item is the last. If so, he will

1. Set the previous item `ProjectTreeItemViewModel.IsLast` to `false`, which will re-trigger
   the `MultiBinding` for the previous item to show the line.
2. Set the the current `ProjectTreeItemViewModel.IsLast` to `true`.
3. Return the appropriate `Visibility`.

**TreeLineVisibilityConverter.cs**

```
public class TreeLineVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem) values[0];
    ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
    int lastIndex = ic.Items.Count - 1;

    bool isLastItem = (ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == lastIndex);
    if (isLastItem)
    {
      ResetIsLastOfPrevousItem(ic.Items.Cast<ProjectTreeItemViewModel>(), lastIndex);
      (item.DataContext as ProjectTreeItemViewModel).IsLast = true;
    }

    return isLastItem 
      ? Visibility.Hidden 
      : Visibility.Visible;
  }

  private void ConvertBack(IEnumerable<ProjectTreeItemViewModel> items, int lastIndex)
  {
    ProjectTreeItemViewModel previousItem = items.ElementAt(lastIndex - 1);
    if (previousItem.IsLast && items.Count() > 1)
    {
      previousItem.IsLast = false;
    }
  }

  public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

**`ControlTemplate` of `TreeViewItem`**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  ...

  <!-- line that follows a tree view item -->
  <Border Name="LineToNextItem">
    <Border.Visibility>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TreeLineVisibilityConverter}">
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
        <Binding Path="IsLast" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </Border.Visibility>
  </Border>

  ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

### Remarks

For performance reasons you should consider to add a `Parent` property to your `ProjectTreeItemViewModel`. It's more efficient to traverse the model tree, than traversing the visual tree. Then in your `ControlTemplate` you simply replace the binding to the `TemplatedParent` (`TreeViewItem`) with a binding to the `DataContext` of the `ControlTemplate` e.g., `{Binding}` (or `<Binding />` in case of the `MultiBinding`), which will return the current `ProjectTreeItemViewModel`. From here you can check if it's the last by accessing the `ProjectTreeItemViewModel.Children` property via the `ProjectTreeItemViewModel.Parent`. This way you don't have use the `ItemContainerGenerator` and don't have to cast the items of the `ItemsControl.Items` to `IEnumerable<ProjectTreeItemViewModel>`.

---

---

### MVVM tree view example

This is a simple example on how to build a tree using MVVM. This example pretends to create the data tree from a text file.
See the `ProjectTreeItem` class to see how to traverse the tree using recursion e.g. `GetTreeRoot()`.

At the end is also a revised version of the `TreeLineVisibilityConverter` to show how you can get to the parent collection using the `Parent` reference (and therefore without any need of `static` properties).

**ProjectTreeItem.cs**

```
// The data view model of the tree items.
// Since this is the binding source of the TreeView,
// this class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
// This classes property setters are simplified.
public class ProjectTreeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Default constructor
  /// </summary>
  public ProjectTreeItem(string data)
  {
    this.Data = data;
    this.Parent = null;
    this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItem>();
  }

  // Traverse tree and expand subtree.
  public ExpandChildren()
  {
    foreach (var child in this.Children)
    {
      child.IsExpanded = true;
      child.ExpandChildren();
    }
  }

  // Traverse complete tree and expand each item.
  public ExpandTree()
  {
    // Get the root of the tree
    ProjectTreeItem rootItem = GetTreeRoot(this);
    foreach (var child in rootItem.Children)
    {
      child.IsExpanded = true;
      child.ExpandChildren();
    }
  }

  // Traverse the tree to the root using recursion.
  private ProjectTreeItem GetTreeRoot(ProjectTreeItem treeItem)
  {
    // Check if item is the root
    if (treeItem.Parent == null)
    {
      return treeItem;
    }

    return GetTreeRoot(treeItem.Parent);
  }

  public string Data { get; set; }
  public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
  public ProjectTreeItem Parent { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
// A model class in the sense of MVVM
public class Repository
{
  public ProjectTreeItem ReadData()
  {
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("/path/to/data");

    // Create the tree structure from the file data
    return CreateDataModel(lines);
  }

  private ProjectTreeItem CreateDataModel(string[] lines)
  {
    var rootItem = new ProjectTreeItem(string.Empty);

    // Pretend each line contains tokens separated by a whitespace,
    // then each line is a parent and the tokens its children.
    // Just to show how to build the tree by setting Parent and Children.
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
      rootItem.Children.Add(CreateNode(line));
    }

    return rootItem;
  }

  private ProjectTreeItem CreateNode(string line)
  {
    var nodeItem = new ProjectTreeItem(line);
    foreach (string token in line.Split(' '))
    {
      nodeItem.Children.Add(new ProjectTreeItem(token) {Parent = nodeItem});
    }

    return nodeItem;
  }
}
```

**DataController.cs**

```
// Another model class in the sense of MVVM
public class DataController
{
  public DataController()
  {
    // Create the model. Alternatively use constructor 
    this.Repository = new Repository();
  }

  public IEnumerable<ProjectTreeItem> GetData()
  {
    return this.Repository.ReadData().Children;
  }

  private Repository Repository { get; set; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
// The data view model of the tree items.
// Since this is a binding source of the view,
// this class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
// This classes property setters are simplified.
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    // Create the model. Alternatively use constructor injection.
    this.DataController = new DataController();
    Initialize();
  }

  private void Initialize()
  {
    IEnumerable<ProjectTreeItem> treeData = this.DataController.GetData();
    this.TreeData = new ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItem>(treeData);
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItem> TreeData { get; set; }

  private DataController DataController { get; set; }
}
```

**TreeLineVisibilityConverter.cs**

```
public class TreeLineVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    ProjectTreeItem item = values[0] as ProjectTreeItem;

    // If current item is root return
    if (item.Parent == null)
    {
      return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    ProjectTreeItem parent = item?.Parent ?? item;
    int lastIndex = item.Parent.Chilidren.Count - 1;

    bool isLastItem = item.Parent.Chilidren.IndexOf(item) == lastIndex);
    if (isLastItem)
    {
      ResetIsLastOfPrevousItem(item.Parent.Chilidren, lastIndex);
      item.IsLast = true;
    }

    return isLastItem 
      ? Visibility.Hidden 
      : Visibility.Visible;
  }

  private void ConvertBack(IEnumerable<ProjectTreeItem> items, int lastIndex)
  {
    ProjectTreeItem previousItem = items.ElementAt(lastIndex - 1);
    if (previousItem.IsLast && items.Count() > 1)
    {
      previousItem.IsLast = false;
    }
  }

  public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  <UserControl.DataContext>

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      ...

      <!-- line that follows a tree view item -->
      <Border Name="LineToNextItem">
        <Border.Visibility>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TreeLineVisibilityConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding Path="IsLast" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Visibility>
      </Border>

      ...
    </ControlTemplate>
  <UserControl.Resources>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeData}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much for explaining the solution so clearly. I will definitely go the route of traversing the model tree as you suggested in your previous comment. I appreciate the quick feedback very much!

Comment: I am happy that I could help you. Yes, you should do this. This doesn't require big changes. You can come back if you need help with this.

Comment: Responded with my implementation of the view model traversal

Comment: Alright , I see. It's not exactly what I meant. But it's a big improvement anyway. I reviewed your `ProjectTreeItemViewModel`, because I wanted to see how you create the tree data structure and got some questions and recommendations. **1)** Inside the `BuildProjectTree()` are you always reading from the same file? **2)** I only see a flat collection of children, but no children added to the children. How do you create the other tree levels? **3)** Is the complete tree stored in `IoC.Application.Channels`?

Comment: **4)** Is `IoC` a static class? If so, you are implementing a big anti-pattern. You shouldn't pass around static classes like IoC containers, factories or resources/repositories. You can never write simple unit tests. Refactoring becomes harder. Code more difficult to understand and to maintain. It looks like you are using `IoC` _everywhere_! At least in your models and in the converter.

Comment: **5)** The data models of the tree items should be light. They should only store data and contain some logic like `ExpandChildren` or `CollapseAllChildren` or `ExpandTree`. No file reading or item creation. This should be handled by a managing class. **6)** Introduce a managing view model e.g. `ApplicationViewModel` which exposes the tree data structure instead of the static `IoC`. This view model receives the tree data from a model, which does all the file I/O and tree creation.

Comment: **7)** Since your code structure and intends are not clear to me I'm not able to refactor your code. Instead I can provide you a small example on how to build and traverse a tree data structure e.g. by using recursion. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, I see where we're missing each other. I'll answer your questions by referencing the number prefixed with an 'A' for answer.                                                               
                                                                                                                                   
**A1.)** Yes, so at startup I read the json data and create a singleton of a JObject (from json.Net library), which I save and name 'JsonObject.', so I can then refer to the same instance within the application's runtime.

Comment: **A1 cont.)** `public static JObject JsonObject { get; set; } = new JObject();`  I'm doing this so I don't have to read the whole file every time I need to select specific tokens or query it in some way. I'm not 100% sure this is absolutely the best way of doing this, but for now it's how I'm doing it. I could think of one possible better way of doing this, but haven't explored it yet, wherein I just read out a chunk of the file I want to target, and then work with the transient instance at that point.

Comment: **A2.)** So, there are only two levels to the tree view UI that will every exist. First level, the root elements are called channels, which do have children called devices, but devices do not have children, they have an array list of items called tags. Tags are not shown on the tree view, but do exist in the json data file. When you click on a device on the tree view, the tags for that device are shown in a datagrid to the right of it. Without going too deep into how the application is built, I will just say that I am never actually traversing
a tree that I have built explicity.

Comment: **A2. cont.)** Only targeting nodes by JSONPath, or through the json.Net functions. This is more fitting with what I'm trying to accomplish. So, when you click to expand a tree node, only at that point do the children of a given root node exist in memory. When the tree node (or channel) is closed, the Children collection
is cleared. However, it does always exist in the json data, just not in the observable collection called Children.

Comment: **A3.)** No, the following call reads the json data into a JObject, which is the static instance I mentioned in A1. I can then query the file to add and remove items from the containing lists, like channels, devices, and tags.So, it's not a tree stucture I build myself based on the data in the file.  `JsonObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(ProjectPath.BaseDataFullPath));`

Comment: **A4.)** No, `IoC` is not a static class. `IoC.Application` is a shortcut to access the static instance of the `ApplicationViewModel`, which contains the observable collection for `Channels`. I'm actually already doing exactly what you are saying in Q5, where
the creating of items is handled by a managing class and when items are created they gather information from the view model, but are created under the structure of a model, following the MVVM pattern. So, `IoC.Application.Channels` is merely a reference
to the Channels collection that exists in the `ApplicationViewModel`.

Comment: **A5.)** They are, except for one line that I will be restructing eventually:  `JsonObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(ProjectPath.BaseDataFullPath));` This line in the `ProjectTreeViewModel` class does read in the json file when the class is loaded, but will be moved out to the file manager later.

Comment: **A6.)** Addressed in A4.

**A7.)** Yeah, there is a lot of code I would have to post to explain the full context, but it would be off topic for this question.I am familiar with traversing a tree recursively, but it's just not quite what I need to do in this instance. I do very much appreciate
you taking the time to write all that out and you explained it all very well. So, I am not traversing a view model tree that I explicitly build in code, but am taking advantage of the properties of the `JObject` class in json.NET to find nodes.

Comment: **A7 cont.)** It allows me to find the node I need by simply saving a reference to the full path of the de-serialized class instance and for that reason, I really don't need a full tree structure built out on top of the inheritance hierarchy built in to every `JContainer` in json.NET. With that being said, I'm sure at some point I will refactor this and test out other methods, but for now it's working pretty well and fast. Thanks again for taking the time to help out!

Comment: Addressed your questions 1-7, but didn't know you can only edit a comment within a window of 5 minutes, so didn't get to tag you on all of them.

Comment: @JustinTime Thank you for your time. I really appreciate your detailed answers. So I got the wrong picture, I admit. I thought you have the full tree structure at some point. Regarding **A2)**, just consider to keep nodes or channels in memory, once you've created them. This will speed up expanding nodes, at least the second time. Memory is cheap and always present in high capacity on any modern machine. No need to delete data which is likely to be reused again. I think speed over memory is the common today's paradigm.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree with that: comment editing can be quite annoying. But don't worry because of the missing tags. As long you write a comment under my post, I'll get a notification. All the best with your project. Hope to see you again.

Comment: Can I ask you another question about the binding technique in the tree view control template: The binding fires as you would expect when adding an item to the collection, but does not fire when an item is removed. Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Nevermind that recent question, I just hooked into the CollectionChanged event for each of the view model's observable collection and updated the IsLast property accordingly when an item is removed. I'm still not 100% sure as to why the converter gets called when adding, but not when removing from the collection.

Comment: @JustinTime Sorry for answering this late. There are two reasons which execute the converter: **1.** item added. This is because when an item is added the `DataTemplate` is applied to the item container, the `TreeViewItem` (triggered by the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event). This forces all bindings to execute in order to initialize the template's elements. **2.** The other execution trigger of the converter is when the property `IsLast` has changed.

Comment: In fact, removing e.g. the last item won't trigger anything in order to adjust the `IsLast` property of the new last item as `IsLast` is the only dynamic property which changes after initialization (see first paragraph of my answer). **Solution:** when you remove the items manually use the `ParentIndex` to get the new last item and set `IsLast` to `true`. No need for the extra code to handle the `CollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @BionicCode for the help here, means a lot. I wanted to share my implementation of view model traversal in lieu of visual tree traversal. I ended up not creating a field to reference the parent container in the ProjectTreeItemViewModel class, but instead created a ParentIndex and a ChildIndex that allows me to quickly access the item I need by referencing the FullPath property, which is just the JSONPath to the json content. Honestly, I'm not quite sure how you meant to include a reference to the parent container in the class, but would like to see your suggested implementation. Thanks again, @BionicCode, have a good weekend!

**Here's my the converter now:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Visibility converter for the connecting lines on the tree view UI
    /// </summary>
    public class ConnectingLineVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the proper visibility according to location on the tree view UI
        /// </summary>
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType = null, object parameter = null, CultureInfo culture = null)
        {
            ProjectTreeItemViewModel viewModel = (ProjectTreeItemViewModel)values[0];

            //-- collection context by default is the channels
            var collection = IoC.Application.Channels;
            int currentIndex = viewModel.ParentIndex;

            if (viewModel.Type == ProjectItemType.Device) {
                //-- change the collection context to the children of this channel
                collection = collection[currentIndex].Children;
                currentIndex = viewModel.ChildIndex;
            }

            int lastIndex = collection.Count - 1;
            bool isLastItem = (currentIndex == lastIndex);

            //-- is it the last of it's branch?
            if (isLastItem) {
                ResetPreviousSibling(collection, lastIndex);
                viewModel.IsLast = true;
            }

            return isLastItem ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resets the previous sibling IsLast flag once a new item is added to the collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collection">The collection to search</param>
        /// <param name="lastIndex">The index of the previous sibling</param>
        private void ResetPreviousSibling(ObservableCollection<ProjectTreeItemViewModel> collection, int lastIndex)
        {
            //-- there's only one item in the collection
            if (lastIndex == 0)
                return;

            //-- get the previous sibling and reset it's IsLast flag, if necessary
            ProjectTreeItemViewModel previousSibling = collection[lastIndex - 1];
            if (previousSibling.IsLast)
                previousSibling.IsLast = false;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes = null, object parameter = null, CultureInfo culture = null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Then, the binding becomes...**

```
    <!-- connecting line to the next item -->
    <Border Name="LineToNextItem" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1 0 0 0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderBrush="Blue">
        <Border.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConnectingLineVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding />
                <Binding Path="IsLast" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Visibility>
    </Border>
```